# Find almost-duplicate strings in Objective-C on iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, nsstring

I have a list of song tracks that I uploaded from the iTunes API. Some of them are duplicates, but not perfect duplicates. For example, one might say "All 4 u" vs "All for you", or  "Some song" vs "some song feat. some other artist"

I want to be able to identify the duplicates. Is the best way to compute the Levenshtein distance for all pairs? That seems excessive.

I'm working in the Cocoa Touch framework for iOS programming so if anyone knows of any libraries that would help a lot.

Comment: Lots of luck!  Song names are often not unique, and those that in theory are are often abbreviated in a way as to render them ambiguous.

Comment: The Levenshtein distance is usually calculated iteratively: you fill up a matrix with values increasing monotonically from top left to bottom right where at the end the bottom right field is the Levenshtein distance. 
You would usually interpret two strings as not being duplicates if the distance exceeds a certain value (maybe scaled with the length of the strings). 
Hence, you could implement it in an optimized way by stopping early if the distance is larger than some value. 
Also, you probably don't need to bother with the Levenshtein distance if the lengths of the strings differ strongly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why do you consider computing the Levenshtein distance excessive? What algorithm would you use if you were sitting down to a list with pencil and paper?

That said, Levenshtein is likely necessary, but not sufficient. I would start by normalizing the strings. In some cases, a string might normalize a couple of ways and you'll need to do both. Normalization would look like:

- convert to lowercase
- Strip any leading numbers followed by punctuation ( "1.", "1 - ", etc.)
- Tentatively strip anything after "feat." or "with"

  - This is an example of special knowledge about your problem set. You're going to have to use a lot of special knowledge like this.
  - "Tentatively" means you should probably keep both the stripped and non-stripped versions of the string
  - Keep in mind that things including "feat." might be remixes, so you have to be careful about assuming duplicates. This is of course true of almost any attempt at de-dupping. There are often multiple versions.
- Tentatively expand common abbreviations (u=>you, 4=>for, 2=>two, w/=>with, etc. etc.)
- Tentatively strip anything in parentheses
- Strip English articles (a, an, the). Maybe even strip all very short words (3 or less characters) as a first pass.

Doing this well is complicated and will require a lot of trial and error. I've done a lot of contact de-dupping in the past, and one piece of advice: start conservative. It is very easy to accidentally de-dupe way too much. Build a big list of test data that you've de-duped by hand and test, test, test after every algorithm change. Make sure your UI can present the user with anything you're uncertain about, because there are going to be many, many records that you can't be certain about. (This is true even when you do it by hand. Look at a big list of human-entered titles and tell me which ones are duplicates 100% without listening to the tracks. A computer isn't going to do better than you at this.)

I'm not aware of any publicly available library for this. It's been solved by many people many times (search for "dedupe song titles" or anything similar). But it's generally commercial software.

One more piece of advice for this, since it's a huge O(n^2) or worse problem. Look for bucketing opportunities. If you can match artists first, then albums, then tracks, you can divide and conquer in much less time.

Comment: great ideas. I'll give'er a run. Thanks!